# Cocoa - calling method with multiple arguments

Tags: cocoa

I'm a beginner on Cocoa and I have question about calling method with multiple arguments. I'm writing some data into bluetooth (in sync method) and wait for reply. On another method I'm trying to check that new data was received in buffer but I don't know how I can call this method. I tried many different methods and I can't :(

This method which I try to call is:

```
- (void) odczyt:(IOBluetoothRFCOMMChannel *)rfcommChannel data:(void *)dataPointer     length:(size_t)dataLength
{
    unsigned char *dataAsBytes = (unsigned char *)dataPointer;

    while ( dataLength-- )
    {
        [self addThisByteToTheLogs:*dataAsBytes];
        dataAsBytes++;
    }
}
```

How I should call this method? This method is responsible for reading incoming string and rewriting it to a label. Without calling this method when the button is pressed (and request for data is sent to BT) I'm not able read the incoming data - the label is empty and works after next pushing the button (when the method is exited and the main thread is initialized).

Ok - because its the same class I tried to use:

```
[self odczyt:IOBluetoothRFCOMMChannel *) data:(void *) length:(size_t)];
```

but Im getting an error -  expected expression!
What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should relook at what you want to do.

More to the point, I would post more general questions in the future.

From your title, you wanna know how to call a method with multiple prameters.

If this is correct, then:

```
[self someMethod:pram1 whichAlsoTake:pram2 andHasLogginStat:pram3] // if the method is part of your current class
```

or

```
[SomeClass someMethod:pram1 whichAlsoTake:pram2 andHasLogginStat:pram3] //if part of another class and its public
```

or

```
SomeClass *somethingFromAClass = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
[somethingFromAClass someMethod:pram1 whichAlsoTake:pram2 andHasLogginStat:pram3] // on an instance of a class
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I tried call that like above, but I got error. I made syntax error?

Comment: Can you tell me what error it was. Or upload some more code.